# jQuery on Wordpress - Second action not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i've added the following code to some open/close boxes on my site's home page, the first section is working fine, every step is being followed. However the second isn't being actioned, any ideas?

```
jQuery(".close1").click(function(){
    jQuery( this ).css("margin-bottom", "328px");
    jQuery( this ).addClass("open1");
    jQuery( ".closed1").css({"position": "relative", "top": "285px", "color": "#000"});
    jQuery( ".closed1 h3").css("top", "13px");
    jQuery( ".closed1 p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    jQuery( this ).removeClass("close1");
});

jQuery(".open1").click(function(){
    jQuery( this ).addClass("close1");
    jQuery( this ).css("margin-bottom", "none");
    jQuery( ".closed1 p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    jQuery( this ).removeClass("open1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate your events

```
jQuery("body").on('click','.close1',function(){
    jQuery( this ).css("margin-bottom", "328px");
    jQuery( this ).addClass("open1");
    jQuery( ".closed1").css({"position": "relative", "top": "285px", "color": "#000"});
    jQuery( ".closed1 h3").css("top", "13px");
    jQuery( ".closed1 p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    jQuery( this ).removeClass("close1");
});

jQuery("body").on'click','.open1',function(){
    jQuery( this ).addClass("close1");
    jQuery( this ).css("margin-bottom", "none");
    jQuery( ".closed1 p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    jQuery( this ).removeClass("open1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two events, you could implement "jQuery.toggle()".

**Ex.**

**jQuery :**

```
jQuery( "#book" ).hide();
 jQuery( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
   jQuery( "#book" ).toggle();
 });
```

**Html :**

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<p id="book">
  Toggle
</p>
```

[Tested Code here !](https://jsfiddle.net/hkcn3hdp/6/)